# Proof $\sigma_{\min}(A\Delta)\geq\sigma_{\min}(A)\sigma_{\min}(\Delta)$, $\sigma$ is a singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

Let $A$ and $\Delta$ be square matrices.

The definition of smallest singular value of a matrix $A$. (in title, $\sigma_{\min}$):

[image]

**The matrix norm is the 2-induced norm.**

The propertie:

[image]

I don't understand one step of the proof below:

[image]

Comment: The statement in bold face is **very** wrong: the *smallest* singular value of a matrix isn't a matrix norm, as it can be zero for a nonzero matrix; also, the induced 2-norm is the *largest* rather than the smallest singular value. Anyway, the step marked by the red arrow is just a direct consequence of singular value decomposition.

Comment: I just meant that the norm being used is the 2-induced norm (it's the book convention when there isnt information about which is the norm that is showing) and I didnt meant that the smallest single value is a norm. Anyway, could you explain me better the step marked by the arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A^\ast A$ is positive semidefinite, it can be unitarily diagonalised as $A^\ast A=UDU^\ast$, where $U$ is unitary and $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is the eigenvalue matrix with $d_1\ge\cdots\ge d_n\ge0$. Since $U$ is unitary, the constraint $\|x\|=1$ is equivalent to $\|Ux\|=1$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\underline{\sigma}(A)
&=\min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|
=\sqrt{\min_{\|x\|=1}x^\ast A^\ast Ax}
=\sqrt{\min_{\|x\|=1}(Ux)^\ast D(Ux)}\\
&=\sqrt{\min_{\|y\|=1}y^\ast Dy}
=\sqrt{\min_{\|y\|=1}\sum_i d_i|y_i|^2}
=\sqrt{d_n},
\end{align}
where the minimum occurs at $y=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. Now it is easy to explain the step marked by the red arrow. Let $x$ be any unit vector and $v=U\Delta x=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)^T$. Then $\sum_i|v_i|^2=\|U\Delta x\|^2=\|\Delta x\|^2$ and
\begin{align}
x^\ast \Delta^\ast A^\ast A\Delta x
=(U\Delta x)^\ast D (U\Delta x)
=\sum_i d_i|v_i|^2
\ge d_n\sum_i |v_i|^2
=\underline{\sigma}(A)^2\|\Delta x\|^2.
\end{align}
Taking the minima and square roots on both sides, we obtain the inequality in question.

Comment: hello, I am sorry but could you explain me why (or send some reference) $\sqrt{\min_{\|y\|=1}y^\ast Dy}
=\sqrt{\min_{\|y\|=1}\sum_i d_i|y_i|^2}
=\sqrt{d_n}$ and why the minimum occurs at $y=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)^T$? Kind of weak here :/

Comment: @gustavoreche Every $d_i$ is $\ge d_n$. So the LHS is $\ge\sqrt{d_n\min_{\|y\|=1}\sum_i|y_i|^2}=\sqrt{d_n}$, i.e. $\sqrt{d_n}$ is a lower bound. But this lower bound is attainable at $y=(0,0,\ldots,1)$. Hence it is the minimum.

Comment: @ user1551 finally got the whole thing, one last thing though: Can I take minima and square in any order that I want?

Comment: @gustavoreche Sure. On $[0,\infty)$, $x_1>x_2$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{x_1}>\sqrt{x_2}$. So, a nonnegative quantity attains its minimum if and only if its square root attains minimum. That's why you can interchange the order of square root and minimisation.

Comment: And.. the equality holds if every $d_i=0$ ?

Comment: Huh? No. Equality holds if $y=(0,0,\ldots,0,\pm1)^T$. If $d_n$ is not strictly smaller than $d_{n-1}$, there may be other minimisers. The $d_i$s are given by $A$. You cannot manipulate them.